# MOSFETs heat up in a BLDC controller

Tags: mosfet, pwm, brushless-dc-motor

I am trying to build a BLDC controller.

I have the following schematic:

[image]

I should mention that for the gate drivers I used IR2101 ICs. Everything works fine but when I connect the motor (350W hoverboard motor, the VBAT+ is 36 volts) the motors spin but I have to disconnect it because the MOSFETs get really hot. Without the motor the MOSFETs don't heat at all.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: The problem was because the low side gates didn't turn off fast enough. If you have the same problem try to put an "anti-parallel diode" on the low side MOSFETS. The diode should be a Schottky one (fast diode.)

Comment: What current is the motor drawing?

Comment: 5 up to 9 Amps.

Comment: Oh, there's so many possibilities.  Do you have heat sinks on the FETs?  Are you limiting the duty cycle so that the high-side parts always get gate drive?  Are you actually driving the FETs with no motor attached?  Have you tried driving three resistors in a Y or delta connection to see what happens?  Add your answers to your question, in the form of a narrative of what you've done so far.

Comment: Can you check if the gates are getting driven to the right voltage? If the gates are not driven high enough, FETS will dissipate a lot of power

Comment: The question is why is this happening when i connect the motor. Without the load, the mosfets switch accordingly and don't short out.

Comment: Show oscillograms!

Comment: @pantarhei - Hi, If you believe you have solved the problem yourself (as seems true according to the update you added to the question), then please write that solution into an answer of your own. (As *winny* asked, putting scope traces in your answer would be good). Then, if no-one provides a better answer, accept your answer (to show to the website "back end" that the question can be removed from the "unanswered list" etc.) and *remove the solution information from the question*. The Stack Exchange model is that solutions go into an *answer* not into an update of the question. Thanks :-)